# Laravel update one to many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, one-to-many

I have two table the first is **subjects table** and the second is **subjects_doctors table**. The relationship here is **One To Many**.

> Update method code:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this -> validate($request, [
            'name'          => 'required',
            'max_students'  => 'required',
            'doctors'       => 'required',
            'description'   => 'required'
        ]);

        $subject = Subject::find($id);
        $subject -> name            = $request -> name;
        $subject -> description     = $request -> description;
        $subject -> max_students    = $request -> max_students;
        $subject -> save();
//PROBLEM
        $y = Subject::where('id', $subject -> id) -> doctors() -> update(['doctor_id' => $request -> doctors]);


        Session::flash('success', 'Subject has been updated successfully!');
        return redirect() -> route('subjects.index');
    }
```

The `$request` variable contain an array that have all the updated doctors **id**.

> For Example

I have in the **subjects table** that `subject 1 HAVE 1 DOCTOR` and I have updated it to  `SUBJECT 1 HAVE 2 DOCTORS` .. How I do that?

I have everything in variables but I can't update them in the `subjects_doctors` table.

Answer (score 2):

The problem has been solved by using the **sync()** function from Laravel. Thanks.

> here is the code it may help

```
$subject = Subject::find($id);
    $subject -> name            = $request -> name;
    $subject -> description     = $request -> description;
    $subject -> max_students    = $request -> max_students;
    $subject -> save();

    $subject -> doctors() -> sync($request -> doctors);
```

Comment: Thanks for your solutions. u saved my day.